# Why retrofit appending "?roundtrip=true" in my service url?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using retrofit in android app for network calls. This is what I've done to call web service :

```
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
            .add(hostName, "sha256/#####################")
            .add(hostName, "sha256/#####################")
            .add(hostName, "sha256/#####################")
            .build();

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
            .build();

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
```

After service call, I'm getting following message in onResponse() method :

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=https://hostname/myServiceMethod?Type=xyz?roundtrip=true}
```

Below is my interface code :

```
@Headers({"Accept:application/xyz-v1.0+json"})
@GET("/methodName/{id}/abc?type=ABC")
Call<JsonElement> getServerData(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers, @Path("id") String id);
```

Retrofit appending **?roundtrip=true** at the end of URL. And just because of this, I'm getting code as 404, Not Found.
Can somebody please explain me why this is happening ? And how to remove this **?roundtrip=true** ?

Comment: Can you add code from your interface, where you specified url call ?

Comment: @NaitikSoni please see updated code for interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Retrofit is the reason. I would suggest that you are using some loggers/interceptors that adding "?roundtrip=true" query to intercepted request. I had similar issue once, by accidently adding query param to LoggingInterceptor. I would suggest just to search project source code for "roundtrip" usages:

In case you are using Android Studio / Intellij IDEA:
Right click on module/package > find in path > "roundtrip"

I assume one of the search results would answer your question - where it comes from.